# Extract video frames in Swift using Metal GPU

Tags: swift, macos, avplayer, metal, avassetimagegenerator

I am trying to create a small macOS application that grabs a bunch of frames from a video depending on a timing factor, the video is dragged from the user computer and dropped into the application, something similar to the movie editors (e.g iMovie)

**ex**: factor = 5 -> get a frame each 5 seconds.

Currently I am using this code from `AVAssetImageGenerator`:

```swift
        let imageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
        imageGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
        imageGenerator.requestedTimeToleranceAfter = .zero
        imageGenerator.requestedTimeToleranceBefore = .zero
        imageGenerator.generateCGImagesAsynchronously(forTimes: times) { requestedTime, cgImage, _, _, _ in
              // Do Something with CGImage
        }
```

However, this function seems to take a lot of time to be finished especially that I am passing 6 different factors from 1 to 6.

This calculation should be fast, the user shouldn't wait a lot especially if he has like 120 min video :)

The question is, can we use Metal to run the code above on GPU in order to make it faster? and how other software generate frames quickly without any delay?

Comment: Have you tried setting the time tolerance values to something less accurate (or leave them on default) and see if this speeds up the process?

Comment: It may be faster, but the goal to get accurate results, also if the video is 120 min, I don't think by this the problem will be fixed

Comment: I understand. I was just curious if and how much of an impact those parameters have. It might help to understand the cause of the performance loss.

Comment: I see. Any idea how other software does this?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe going a level deeper and using Video Toolbox for the decoding might help.

Comment: hmmm yeah, we could have better results with Video Toolbox. Anyway any idea how to make the same code above works on Metal GPU?

Comment: I would guess the `AVAssetImageGenerator` would already use the most optimal approach for decoding the video frames. If that means using the GPU, it probably will do so automatically. I guess the performance killer here is your precision requirement in combination with a keyframe-based video codec.